# Symfony 2 - Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Any ideas what is causing this error? In my local MAMP environment I do not have any issues, once pushed up to an Ec2 instance it starts appearing.

```
ForbiddenOverwriteException: Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.
in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php line 156
at BaseNode->merge() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php line 347
at ArrayNode->mergeValues() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php line 167
at BaseNode->merge() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Processor.php line 36
at Processor->process() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Processor.php line 52
at Processor->processConfiguration() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/Extension.php line 101
at Extension->processConfiguration() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php line 53
at SecurityExtension->load() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 42
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php line 119
at Compiler->compile() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php line 437
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 872
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 783
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 517
at Kernel->boot() in /var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 548
at Kernel->handle() in /var/www/html/web/app.php line 17
```

Comment: I have symfony2 app on ec2 and have no issue. One thing I can think of that causes this is maybe you are loading different config file on ec2? I often do the mistakes when I was testing with config_dev, and on production I run with config_prod and got errors.

Comment: Ahh you were right, small typo in assetic path. my bad. If add your comment as an answer i'll accept. Thanks.